# MXnet : Error in continuing training a model loaded from file

Tags: python, deep-learning, mxnet

I also post this question in the [repository](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/issues/8023).

I'm trying to load a model previously saved in files following the tutorial [here](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/versions/master/tutorials/python/predict_image.html). I use exactly the same command as shown in the tutorial, but I meet with the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 153, in <module>
    num_epoch=num_epoch)
  File "/home/mypath/software/try_mxnet2/mxnet/python/mxnet/module/base_module.py", line 496, in fit
    self.update_metric(eval_metric, data_batch.label)
  File "/home/mypath/software/try_mxnet2/mxnet/python/mxnet/module/module.py", line 735, in update_metric
    self._exec_group.update_metric(eval_metric, labels)
  File "/home/mypath/software/try_mxnet2/mxnet/python/mxnet/module/executor_group.py", line 567, in update_metric
    for label, axis in zip(labels, self.label_layouts):
TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration
```

The code of loading and retraining the files is as follows:

```
sym, arg_params, aux_params = mx.model.load_checkpoint('../model/test_mymodel', 25)
lenet_model = mx.mod.Module(symbol=sym, context=mx.gpu(), label_names=None)

lenet_model.bind(for_training=True, data_shapes=[('data', (batch_size,3,16,16))], 
         label_shapes=lenet_model._label_shapes)
lenet_model.set_params(arg_params, aux_params, allow_missing=True)
lenet_model.fit(train_iter,
                optimizer='adam',
                optimizer_params={'learning_rate':0.001,'wd':0.0005},
                eval_metric='acc',
                batch_end_callback = mx.callback.Speedometer(batch_size, n_report), 
                epoch_end_callback  = mx.callback.do_checkpoint("../model/test_mymodel", 5),
                num_epoch=num_epoch)
```

As I have tested, when I comment out the line `lenet_model.fit(...)`, no error is reported. It seems the loaded model cannot be trained continuously, or there is something wrong with my code.

I'm looking forward to kind solutions. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mind sharing the /model/test_mymodel.py file?

Comment: @rgaut . There is no `test_mymodel.py` file. The `test_mymodel` is the prefix of the model files. It is something like `test_mymodel-0000.params`.

Comment: Is there any way I can reproduce it locally.

Comment: Can you train (fit) it if you start with a random vanilla network? You might have issues with you data iterators.

Answer (score 0):

The response in the repo https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/issues/8023 clarifies that this is a shape mismatch error in the code.